# How to get the code causing an issue in SonarQube or a link to it?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

Is there a way to parameter the SonarQube web service to get the line of the code causing a specific error?

For instance, if I parameter the webservice to get all the blocking issues like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?severities=BLOCKER
```

the Json returned gives the line's number of the issues but not the line's code. How to have the code of those lines?

Otherwise, is there a possibility to get a link to the line causing the error?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out the WebAPI documentation embedded in your SonarQube server (linked at the footer). For your specific use-case you'll see that this is a good match: *api/sources* .